# JavaScript/jQuery code in (blogger) post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, blogger

How to paste **`JavaScript/jQuery`** code in blogger post?

Such like [jsfiddle.net/tTman](http://jsfiddle.net/tTman)

It didn't work, don't know what I miss?

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective .

(Newbie learning)

Comment: [Webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) might be a good spot to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you did not load the `jquery` library. Pasting the following code in the `HTML` view of a blog-post should work:

```
<img id="b" src="http://www.web-press.it/folder/servizi_cloud.jpg" id="b" style="position:absolute; top:50px"/>

<!-- Loading the required JQuery library -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function moveRight(){
        $("#b").animate({left: "+=300"}, 2000,moveLeft)
    }

function moveLeft(){
        $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 2000,moveRight)
    }

$(document).ready(function() {

       moveRight();

});
</script>
```

Comment: It seem easier paste on post Html (without affecting my Template -> Edit HTML). But it not moving naturally (like jsfiddle.net/tTman/) jerking... & background white! (same as using Marquee Code) Animated images ".png" or ".gif" transparent background, appears white background. Don't understand why? Any solution encounter this problem? 

Yep no jquery library. Must I have? How?

Comment: In order to execute this JavaScript you will need to have the JQuery library. You can load this library from `ajax.googleapis.com` using the code above.

Comment: ajax.googleapis.com (The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all )

What the steps I new to this 'JQuery library'? Now more confusing

Comment: The easiest way to load the jquery library is by using a hosted solution, for example the one from Google. To do this you can use `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Just make sure you load it before your own code.

Comment: I paste <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
(Template -> Edit HTML)

But not working.

Answer (score 0):

follow this path:

### blogger.com -> Template -> Edit HTML

and past your `javascript/jquery` codes before `</head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveRight(){
        $("#b").animate({left: "+=300"}, 2000,moveLeft)
    }
    function moveLeft(){
        $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 2000,moveRight)
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {

       moveRight();
    });
</script>
```

**see pic:**
[image]

**now!**

go to `Layout` and **add a gadget** and input your HTML code into that!

```
<img id="b" src="http://www.web-press.it/folder/servizi_cloud.jpg" id="b" style="position:absolute; top:50px"/>
```

**see pic:**
[image]

---

## Notice:

you must add `Jquery` libararies before your `Jquery` codes

---

if you want to show this effects only in posts, go to

### blogger.com -> New Posts

and in edditor box, click on `HTML` and past your `HTML Codes` into that

Comment: Thanks! What jquery library? How to create jQuery file, where to put? Recommend any special device? 

I want show this effects in posts. (Lots of scraps sites very confusing)

Comment: @user3739135 download `jquery` library through this link: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: for create jquery file, open notepad, copy/past your jquery codes into that, and save notepad with `.js` type

Comment: copy `<script src='yourdomain/jquery-libararies.js/></script>` <script src='domain/your-jquery-file.js'><script> before `</head>` element

Comment: Open notepad, copy/past your 'jquery codes' and save notepad with .js how? 

May I know only need one js file enough, can create many different codes in posts?

Do I need account store .js file, recommend please? (dropbox can?)

Got a systematic complete short video demonstration show effects only (blogger) post?